Looking for PF1 equivalent of Benign and Baleful Transposition
Benign and baleful transposition are spells from D&D 3.5e that teleport two creatures to each other’s former locations. Benign transposition is lower-level, and can only be cast on the caster’s allies; baleful transposition is a spell level higher and can be cast on any creatures (but those who don’t want the swap may make a Will save to negate the spell).
What I'm looking for is either a Pathfinder 1.0 version of those spells or something as close to them as possible. Possible use cases (might make it easier to pinpoint correct spells):

Teleporting enemy right under our full damage close quarters fighter,
Making enemy eat their own AoE like Web or Black Tentacles,
Getting positional advantage if enemy has better position,
Saving teammate from certain death.

Absolute cherry on top would be if such effect was an immediate action.
Context: Arcanist level 14 Mythic tier 3 (although I have ways to get access to pretty much every spell list, depending on how much I need it to happen), RAW game.

For the record, the site you’d linked to for the details of these spells does not have permission to display them, and thus may be subject to a cease-and-desist from Wizards of the Coast at any time (they’ve done it before to previous iterations of that very site, even). In order to limit link rot, and out of deference to the people who make the games we enjoy, this site doesn’t allow links to such sites. I’ve replaced those links with descriptions of the spells.

Thanks, didn't know that. Those sites existed for decades, didn't have any problem with those before. But I guess if WotC sends Pinkertons to their consumers one can assume everything evil from them so preemptive measures make sense here.

The primary offensive equivalent would be Hostile Juxtaposition. It's built around the "make the enemy eat their own AoE" use case, being cast as a standard action and discharged as an immediate action when you are attacked.
The general case of swapping with an ally appears to be in the form of King's Castle, which is potentially awkward due to being only on the Paladin spell list. There is a more generally available spell (Master's Escape) but it only works with your own summons.
All of these do require the caster to be one of the targets swapped, while the 3.5 versions appear to allow swapping of two other creatures.

King's Castle looks interesting. Shouldn't be hard to craft it as in at-will item if my teammates say it will be useful enough.
